# How to get values before/after a number from an array?

Tags: javascript

I have range 1000 - 1200

I want to exclude numbers 1002, 1030 and 1040 and get the range before and after them like this:

```
1000 - 1001
1003 - 1029
1031 - 1039
1041 - 1200
```

I have now this where I can enter numbers and get the array back.

For second part I am using jQuery plugin but I think I need to do something else to be able to pass array as a parameter.

Also I don't know how to get the ranges before and after the `exclusion`

```
function range(first, second) {
    list = []
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    for (var i = first; i <= second; i++) {
        list.push(i)
    }
    return list;
}
a = new range(1, 5)
console.log(a + " this is the original list")

exclusion = 3 //should be a array

listExcluded = jQuery.grep(list, function (value) {
    return value != exclusion;
});

console.log(listExcluded + " this is value without excluded number")
```

Comment: Hi. Please take some time to improve your question's title, as it is, it's of no use for someone searching the site

Comment: the same you do in any other language.

Comment: Done, edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple sample... can probably be optimized by js experts.

```js
function range(first, second) {
    this.list = []
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    for (var i = first; i <= second; i++) {
        this.list.push(i)
    }
    return this.list;
}

var a = new range(1, 10)

console.log(a + " this is the original list")

var ec = [3,6];  // should be a array

var b = [];      // new array holding the sliced arrays
var start = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= ec.length; i++) {
  
  if (i == ec.length) {  
    b.push(a.slice(start))
    
  } else {  
    b.push(a.slice(start,ec[i]-1))
    start = ec[i];

  }
      
}

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  console.log("Array nr:" + (i+1) + ": " + b[i])
}
```

Comment: Yes this works fine but what im still missing is the part where I will create like sub arrays to hold the values before and after the exclusions.

I mean here I should have the following arrays:
1. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2. [1,2]
3. [4,5]
4. [7,8,9,10]

I would need the arrays 2-4 to print out the ranges for numbers before/after the excluded values.

Comment: @Villemh Updated my answer, and the "b" variable is an array with the extracted arrays, so I added a loop iterating the "b" array, showing it's there.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an algorithm, not something specific to Javascript, nor JQuery.
Try something like that:

```
var initialList = range(1000, 1200);
var exclusions = [1002, 1030, 1040];

var result = [];
var currentSubList = [];
initialRange.forEach(function (v) {
    if (exclusions.indexOf(v) > -1) {
        if (currentSubList.length > 0) {
            result.push(currentSubList);
            currentSubList = [];
        }
    } else {
        currentSubList.push(v);
    }
});
if (currentSubList.length > 0) {
    result.push(currentSubList);
}
```